# If in any triangle ABC, the area $\Delta \le \frac{b^2+c^2}{\lambda}$, then the largest possible numerical value of $\lambda$ is?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

$$\frac 12 bc \sin A \le \frac{b^2+c^2}{\lambda}$$
$$bc(\frac 12 \lambda \sin A-2)\le (b-c)^2$$

I really didn’t understand this well, so this pretty much what any rookie would do. What should I do next?

The answer is 4.

Comment: What kind of number is $\lambda$?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ supposed to be positive?

Comment: No such data has been provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\lambda\sin(\alpha)\le 2\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}\right)$$
since we have $$\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}\geq 2$$ we get $$2\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}\right)\geq 4$$

Answer (score 1):

They are asking what the largest value of $\lambda$ is that makes the inequality valid. It boils down to two issues. First, what is the maximum value of $\sin A$? Secondly, what is the best inequality of the form $bc \leq C(b^2 + c^2)$. The second one is related to the AM GM inequality. Since $\sin A$ is at most $1$ and $C$ is at most ${1 \over 2}$, the best you can do is $\lambda = 4$.

Comment: Why is $C$ at most $\frac 12$

Comment: I just typoed there. $C$ is at most ${1 \over 2}$ in the correction by the AM-GM inequality for example

Comment: So is $C$ the angle $C$ or some constant?

Comment: some constant actually